# MySQL How to calculate Partnership Scores from Cricket ball by ball database [Solved]

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to create a simple cricket application, where i will store all cricket records from a database. I collect a sample database with data from online and i successfully did some query but **I'm unable to write the query for finding `Partnership Scored` for a match**. I have no clue how can i do this.

### Below is the three main Table which i will used to get the data:

> **1. ball_by_ball table, this table holds full information by ball by ball:** [image]
>
> **2. batsman_scored, this table holds batsman run scores by ball by ball:** [image]
>
> **3. wicket_taken, this table hold wicket fallen information by ball by ball:** [image]

**I tried below query but I'm unable to group those properly**

```
select P.Player_Name, P1.Player_Name, sum(b.runs_scored) as Runs
from ball_by_ball a
       inner join batsman_scored b using (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no)
       inner join Player P on a.striker = P.Player_Id
       inner join Player P1 on a.non_striker = P1.Player_Id
where a.match_id = 981018
  and a.innings_no = 1 group by P.Player_Name, P1.Player_Name;
```

**So this my output: (this is not what i want)**
[image]

> If you look above screenshot, there Row 1 and 2 will be same, `AJ Finch BB McCullum and BB McCullum AJ Finch` will be same row and the
>   Runs column will be sum. That's what i want but i'm unable to do it.

### UPDATED- This is the finally query which gives the partnership information:

```
select P.Player_Name, Runs + Extra as Partnership, P1.Player_Name
from (select if(striker > non_striker,
                concat(striker),
                concat(non_striker))      as Bat1,
             sum(b.runs_scored)           as Runs,
             ifnull(sum(e.extra_runs), 0) as Extra,
             if(striker > non_striker,
                concat(non_striker),
                concat(striker))          as Bat2
      from ball_by_ball a
             left join batsman_scored b using (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no)
             left join extra_runs e using (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no)
      where a.match_id = 981020
        and a.innings_no = 1
      group by if(striker > non_striker,
                  concat(striker, '-', non_striker),
                  concat(non_striker, '-', striker)), Bat1, Bat2) as t
       inner join Player P on t.Bat1 = P.Player_Id
       inner join Player P1 on t.Bat2 = P1.Player_Id;
```

> **This is the final output which i wanted:** [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grouping is a player pair so your `GROUP BY` expression needs to reflect this. The `striker` / `non_striker` must combined form a unique value. Start with an `IF` statement to avoid duplicates. I've used a mathematical expression that won't cause duplicates.

So with your query use the following group by:

```
GROUP BY IF(striker > non_striker,
            striker * 30 + non_striker,
            non_striker * 30 + striker)
```

This works because assuming all player ids are < 30. If this isn't the case it can be replaced by a higher value.

Alternately you could use a string based mechanism to get `1-2` as unique identifier. Note a separator `-` is needed (and can be anything not in the result set), otherwise `striker,non_striker` value `1,234` would be grouped the same as `12,34`

```
GROUP BY IF(striker > non_striker,
            CONCAT(striker, '-', non_striker),
            CONCAT(non_striker, '-', striker)
```

Comment: well this works only when i don't select striker or non_striker in output, when i select those i have to add those in group by clause thus my result grouped by striker or non_striker and result be the same as my question showing result. so how can i get striker and no_striker by using your solution? or is my query is wrong?

Comment: this is my query by your solution
`select sum(b.runs_scored)           as Runs
from ball_by_ball a
       left join batsman_scored b using (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no)
       inner join Player P on a.striker = P.Player_Id
       inner join Player P1 on a.non_striker = P1.Player_Id
where a.match_id = 981018
  and a.innings_no = 1
group by if(striker > non_striker,
            concat(striker, '-', non_striker),
            concat(non_striker, '-', striker));`

Comment: You could add the `SELECT IF(....) as bater_ids ... GROUP BY bater_ids` but, no grouping or listing them individually doesn't make sense.

Comment: thank you so much for your time, i make it as answer.  without those ids its not clear who is batting. finally the problem solve and i update final query in my question, please have a look at it.